# How do you include a C library (libxml2) when building a Go project for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, go, compilation, libxml2

I have a Go project which I want to build as a binary so that I can deploy it as an AWS Lambda. It uses a [Go wrapper for libxml2](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2) (lestrrat-go) which requires you to have libxml2 installed locally, which I have done via `brew install libxml2`. The wrapper is installed as a git submodule in the project.

I can run unit tests fine with the following bash script:

```sh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig"

go test ./...
```

However I cannot work out how to build my project as a binary so it can be deployed.

I am working on a Mac and have installed the [musl-cross cross compiler](https://github.com/FiloSottile/homebrew-musl-cross) to try and compile the project for linux, which is the OS used on AWS Lambda.

My current build script is as follows:

```sh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig"
export CGO_ENABLED=1
export CC=x86_64-linux-musl-gcc

GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -L /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib" -o bin/main
```

The command fails with the following output:

```
/var/folders/_j/dtvtwt3902x_z20282yqmwy00000gp/T/go-build660707780/b125/_x002.o: In function `MY_setXmlIndentTreeOutput':
vendor/github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib/clib.go:73: undefined reference to `__xmlIndentTreeOutput'
vendor/github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib/clib.go:74: undefined reference to `__xmlIndentTreeOutput'
/var/folders/_j/dtvtwt3902x_z20282yqmwy00000gp/T/go-build660707780/b125/_x002.o: In function `MY_test_node_name':
vendor/github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib/clib.go:163: undefined reference to `xmlIsCombiningGroup'
vendor/github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib/clib.go:163: undefined reference to `xmlCharInRange'
vendor/github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib/clib.go:163: undefined reference to `xmlIsExtenderGroup'
...  many more of these
```

Comment: Since you are using `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (and assuming it is correct), that is just about all you should need for compile and link. You should probably use a `RUNPATH` to ensure the libs are on-path at runtime.  This looks a tad bit unusual: `/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib`. You should probably just use `--prefix=/usr/local`. Headers will be located at `/usr/local/include`, libs at `/usr/local/lib`, and pkg-config files at `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.